# Addon: Allow all scripts a site wants to execute?

Tags: firefox, noscript

When visiting a site that wants to execute scripts, NoScript by default blocks all of them.
Now I want to trust a few sites / domains and allow it to execute scripts like NoScript wasn´t there.
NoScript gives the option "allow *domain*.com" but if the site for example uses services that come from another domain they are blocked and I would have to allow those again...
The thing is I do not want to allow those in general, but for this site.

**So is it possible to allow for one site** (best with one click when first visiting it) **to do everything like without NoScript?**

Or is there another addon for this?

Comment: why do you think that a `referenced-domain.com` would be safe when accessed through `domain-A.com` but not from some other `domain-B.com`?

Comment: You are right with that, but it is not only about safety in terms of attacking scripts, but also if a site uses some services of other domains.
The second point is that I do not want to have to allow each script seperately.

Comment: Am still a little surprised. The allow for NoScript is just once per primary site... yet, we will see if there is another way for you.

Comment: I at least discovered a "remove all restrictions for this site" option in the settings menu that shows up when something is blocked.
But it still seems to just add all domains with scripts to the positive list.